# Web Components In firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, web-component, content-script

I'm trying to use web components inside a Firefox extension but i always get  errors trying to add the needed polyfills to make web components work on firefox.

#### Polyfill using

["webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.0.3"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs)

#### First Attempt - webcomponents-sd-ce.js

```
 "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches":["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce.js", "contentScript.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
```

The error i get is

TypeError: **"importNode" is read-only webcomponents-sd-ce.js:100:457**

Its failing at using the library.  The [example code](https://github.com/oslego/chrome-extension-custom-element) i was working with worked on chrome.  Chrome needed this polyfill because in the context scripts windows there was no 'customElements' property.  Something that is normally default on the user window property list.

#### Second Attempt - webcomponents-bundle.js

```
  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches":["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["webcomponents-bundle.js", "contentScript.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
```

The error i get is

TypeError: **"importNode" is read-only webcomponents-bundle.js:169:460**

I don't normally have problems with these file, so i don't exactly know where the problem originates.  If its a problem between the context's window and the normal window or just in how i'm using it.

Comment: The first solution works for me.